# Angular2 translation after subscribing to service

Tags: angular, ng2-translate

I have a parent component that has a child component, I want to translate the text based on the user language I get it from an api.

Here is my translation pipe transform method:

```
transform(value : string, args: any[]) : any
{   
    if (!value) return ;
    return this._translationService.translate(value) ;
}
```

Translation Service

```
export class TranslationService {

    private _currentLang: string = 'en';

    public use(langId: number): void { 
        this._currentLang =  langId == 0 ? 'fr' : 'en';
    }


    public translate(key: string) {
        //tranlsation happens here

    }
}
```

Here is the Parent component where its getting the langId in ngOnInit()

```
ngOnInit() : void 
{

    this._langService.getLanguageId(this.userId)
                     .subscribe( langId=> { this._translationService.use(langId); });
    }

}
```

In Parent and Child Component Templates I would have used the pipe as this:

```
  <div >{{ 'Caption_Key' | translation }}</div>
```

The child Component is translating the captions before setting the langId of translation service. However the parent component translation is working fine. I see the call is async, but how can I assure that child components would have the correct language before transformation happens.

I tried to use `EventEmitter` and emitting an event when calling the *use(langId)* in the service, then made the pipe to subscribe to the event, but that didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the child component relies on the translation to function properly, then it may be worth considering not instantiating the child component until you know the language.

```
this._langService.getLanguageId(this.userId)
  .subscribe(langId => { 
    this._translationService.use(langId);
    this.translationSet = true; 
  });
}
```

`<child-component *ngIf="translationSet"></child-component>`

EDIT:

A more scalable approach would be to have the `this._translationService.use` do a `translationSubject.emit(language)` after setting the language, and having all components subscribe to the language setting.

Comment: As I understood, If I use a Subject and emit then I would inject the `translationService` in all my components. I was looking to for a way to keep this logic in the pipe itself rather injecting the service and subscribe to the subject emitted in every component.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `APP_INITIALIZER` and execute all pre-bootstrap configurations there. There are tons of example on SO, so I don't want to copy/paste those here. Basically, `APP_INITIALIZER`, if setup properly (e.g. it MUST return 1 promise, even though you have to execute 5 backend requests), is executed before 1st component is `constructor`ed